# Group Attributes by Attribute Set

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, magento-community

Hi

I wonder if is possible to group the attributes by attribute set to layered navigation. Let me expalin what I mean.

Let's say that we make a search to products with various attribute sets.

- Shoes -> shoes-attr-set -> size,style,color
- Car -> car-attr-set -> type,hp,car-color
- Toys -> toys-attr-set -> age,genre

The search returns all products from this categories and display all the attributes to layered navigation. Something like this
size
style
color
type
hp
car-color
age
genre

What I want is to format the layered navigation this way

**Shoes**
- size
- style
- color

**Car**
- type
- hp
- car-color

**Toys**
- age
- genre

Can anybody help me. Thank you

Comment: Shoes
- color

Car
- car-color

both attribute sets color attribute code same or both are different?

Comment: The color is not the problem (i think). This can be a "universal" attribute or something like car_color and shoes_color

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter by attribute set as well, because Attribute sets are not disjunct, so "shoes -> color" should result in different results than "cars -> color", there is no easy solution for this, because the attribute index is used for layered navigation filters and it does not contain information about the attribute set of the products.

On the other hand, if you use different attributes per attribute set (like shoe_color and car_color), you don't need to change functionality of index and search, just change the filter templates to reorder the items:

- load attribute sets with associated filterable attributes, loop over attributes per set
- for each attribute, check if it's in the array of attributes that would be displayed

Comment: The attributes can be different (like shoe_color and car_color). I don't know how to show the attribute set title and how to group associated attributes